# How to get the rendered size of a video from a HTML video element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video

How to get the *rendered* size of a video displayed using the HTML5 `<video>` element?

The [`videoWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/videoWidth) and [`videoHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/videoHeight) properties, suggested as a solution on [other similar (but different!) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129102/html5-video-dimensions)s, return the *[intrinsic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/videoHeight#about_intrinsic_width_and_height)* width and height of the video, so they are not the solution.

The `width` and `height` properties, which are [supposed to return the width and height of the display area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement#instance_properties), return 0, for some reason.

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");
console.log(video.width); //0
console.log(video.height); //0
```

```html
<video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Fine-tuned-Bee-Flower-Coevolutionary-State-Hidden-within-Multiple-Pollination-Interactions-srep03988-s6.ogv" controls></video>
```

Any suggestions?

## Update

The current answers suggest using `getBoundingClientRect()` or `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`. The problem is, as far as I understand, that those return the size of the `<video>` element rather than the size of the actual video pixels rendered on the screen.

For instance, let's say the video's CSS `height` property is set to `100%`, and its `max-width` is set to `100%`. This video is inside a div with a `height` of `1000px`. The value returned by both `getBoundingClientRect().height` and  `clientHeight` is the size of the div (`1000px`), rather than the actual height of the video:

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
  const rect = video.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(rect.height); // ~1000
  console.log(video.clientHeight); // 1000
});
```

```css
#container {
  outline: 3px solid red;
  height: 1000px;
}

video {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Fine-tuned-Bee-Flower-Coevolutionary-State-Hidden-within-Multiple-Pollination-Interactions-srep03988-s6.ogv" controls></video>
</div>
```

Comment: `video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => { const rect = video.getBoundingClientRect(); console.log(rect.width); console.log(rect.height); });`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadedmetadata_event#examples

Comment: @cmgchess - Thank you. This should probably be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: One can probably take a bit from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73534684/how-can-i-translate-between-client-coordinates-of-a-html-video-element-and-pictu/73539962#73539962) of mine where I get the relative position of a mouse event between the screen and the actual video frame, taking into account all the object-fit and object-position combinations. Shouldn't be too hard to only get the bbox of the rendered video from there. (If nobody did by then,n I may spend some time on it tomorrow)

Comment: @Kaiido - Thank you. But does this mean that there isn't any native solution for this? I am a bit shocked.

Comment: No, no native solution for this. Not sure why it's "shoking" though, there aren't many use case for it. What's yours?

Comment: @MichaelHaddad I see your update and now understand what you mean. The solution  for me in the past was to do an **aspect ratio** calculation. My situation was drawing a user-selected video into Canvas. If I remember correctly I had to take the original video input Width and re-scale it to same (output) Width as the container, the aspect ratio calculation then gave a new output Height based on the previously re-scaled Output Width. It worked correctly in Chrome (did not need other browsers for that project). You can try something (aspect ratio calculation) or I can show you IF still needed.

Answer (score 1):

> *"How to get the ***rendered*** size of an HTML5  element?"*

You can try [**clientWidth**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) and **clientHeight** to get the on-screen display size.
The advantage is that you don't need to wait for any metadata loading event. 
It's just there already.

For testing, you could add a `width=""` property to the video tag and see if clientWidth / clientHeight are doing what you want, whenever the rendered width/height is also changed.

Kindly confirm if this meets your expected result..?

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");
console.log("video DISPLAY SIZE:");
console.log("clientWidth: " + video.clientWidth); //300
console.log("clientHeight: " + video.clientHeight); //150
```

```html
<video width="300" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Fine-tuned-Bee-Flower-Coevolutionary-State-Hidden-within-Multiple-Pollination-Interactions-srep03988-s6.ogv" controls></video>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can listen to the [`loadedmetadata`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadedmetadata_event#examples) event of `HTMLMediaElement`

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
  const rect = video.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(rect.width, rect.height);
  console.log(video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
  console.log(video.clientWidth, video.clientHeight);
});
```

```html
<video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Fine-tuned-Bee-Flower-Coevolutionary-State-Hidden-within-Multiple-Pollination-Interactions-srep03988-s6.ogv" controls></video>
```

`getBoundingClientRect()` will take into account transformations, paddings in this example. `clientWidth/Height` will not take into account transformations

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
  const rect = video.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(rect.width, rect.height);
  console.log(video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
  console.log(video.clientWidth, video.clientHeight);
});
```

```css
video {
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  transform: scale(0.5); /* 0.5 times */
}
```

```html
<video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Fine-tuned-Bee-Flower-Coevolutionary-State-Hidden-within-Multiple-Pollination-Interactions-srep03988-s6.ogv" controls></video>
```

here is what `getBoundingClientRect()` gives
250 = (480 x scale(0.5)) + padding-left(5) + padding-right(5)
146 = (272 x scale(0.5)) + padding-top(5) + padding-bottom(5)

Comment: Thank you. After the initial render, can I simply use `getBoundingClientRect()`  whenever I want to get the dimensions?

Comment: Thank you. Let's say the video is inside a `div`, its `height` CSS property is set to `100%`, and `max-width` is set to `100%` (please see example here: https://jsfiddle.net/h1qrpd6z/). Now `getBoundingClientRect()` returns the size of the `div`, and not the size of the video. I believe this is because the `video` element is stretched within the `div`, but I want to get the actual dimensions of the rendered video itself.

Comment: hmm the whole div is considered the rendered video right. i can see the whole thing as a video. maybe you just want it without the extra whitespace?

Comment: Exactly. Just the size of the video itself. I will edit the question to reflect that better. Thank you very much for the effort.

Comment: @MichaelHaddad honestly not sure how to get that value

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct that your initial issue regarding `videoWidth` and `videoHeight` return `0` was due to the media not being loaded yet when you called the getters. You need to wait for at least the *loadedmetadata*  event before you can get access to these values.

Then, the rendered size of the actual video content will depend on both the size of its `<video>` container and its `object-fit` and `object-position` rules.
There is no built-in method to get this info, so you will have to write it yourself and handle all the combinations of these values. For [another related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73534684/how-can-i-translate-between-client-coordinates-of-a-html-video-element-and-pictu/73539962#73539962) I wrote a code that does retrieve the position of the mouse cursor relative to the video frame's coordinate system. We can reuse some of it to get just the bounding box of the rendered video, relative to the `<video>` element.
Note that in below example I use a `<canvas>` element because it's easier to manipulate its intrinsic size, but `<video>` would work just the same.

```js
// Some helpers
/**
 * Returns the intrinsic* width & height of most media sources in the Web API
 * (at least the closest we can get to it)
 */
function getResourceDimensions(source) {
  if (source.videoWidth) {
    return { width: source.videoWidth, height: source.videoHeight };
  }
  if (source.naturalWidth) {
    return { width: source.naturalWidth, height: source.naturalHeight };
  }
  if (source.width) {
    return { width: source.width, height: source.height };
  }
  return null;
}
function isRelative(length) {
  return length?.match?.(/%$/);
}
/**
 * Parses the component values of "object-position"
 * Returns the position in px
 */
function parsePositionAsPx(str, bboxSize, objectSize) {
  const num = parseFloat(str);
  if (isRelative(str)) {
    const ratio = num / 100;
    return (bboxSize * ratio) - (objectSize * ratio);
  }
  return num;
}
function parseObjectPosition(position, bbox, object) {
  const [left, top] = position.split(" ");
  return {
    left: parsePositionAsPx(left, bbox.width, object.width),
    top:  parsePositionAsPx(top, bbox.height, object.height)
   };
}

/**
 * Returns the BBox of the rendered object content 
 * relative to the element's box.
 */
function getRenderedBox(elem) {
  let { objectFit, objectPosition } = getComputedStyle(elem);
  const bbox   = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  const object = getResourceDimensions(elem);
  
  if (objectFit === "scale-down") {
    objectFit = (bbox.width < object.width || bbox.height < object.height)
      ? "contain" : "none";
  }
  if (objectFit === "none") {
    const { left, top } = parseObjectPosition(objectPosition, bbox, object);
    return { left, top, ...object }
  }
  if (objectFit === "contain") {
    const objectRatio = object.height / object.width;
    const bboxRatio   = bbox.height / bbox.width;
    const width  = bboxRatio > objectRatio ? bbox.width : bbox.height / objectRatio;
    const height = bboxRatio > objectRatio ? bbox.width * objectRatio : bbox.height;
    const {left, top} = parseObjectPosition(objectPosition, bbox, {width, height});
    return { left, top, width, height };
  }
  if (objectFit === "fill") {
    // Relative positioning is discarded with `object-fit: fill`,
    // so we need to check here if it's relative or not.
    const [posLeft, posTop] = objectPosition.split(" ");
    const {left, top} = parseObjectPosition(objectPosition, bbox, object);
    return {
      left: isRelative(posLeft) ? 0 : left,
      top: isRelative(posTop) ? 0 : top,
      width: bbox.width,
      height: bbox.height,
    };
  }
  if (objectFit === "cover") {
    const minRatio = Math.min(bbox.width / object.width, bbox.height / object.height);
    let width  = object.width  * minRatio;
    let height = object.height * minRatio;
    let outRatio  = 1;
    if (width < bbox.width) {
      outRatio = bbox.width / width;
    }
    if (Math.abs(outRatio - 1) < 1e-14 && height < bbox.height) {
      outRatio = bbox.height / height;
    }
    width  *= outRatio;
    height *= outRatio;
    
    const { left, top } = parseObjectPosition(objectPosition, bbox, {width, height});
    return { left, top, width, height };
  }
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Usage example - Move a box around the rendered area
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function init() {
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createRadialGradient(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 0, canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, Math.hypot(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2));
  ctx.fillStyle.addColorStop(0, "red");
  ctx.fillStyle.addColorStop(1, "green");
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function updateWitness() {
  /**
   * `getRenderedBox()` returns the position relative to the source element's box
   * Since our witness element is absolutely positionned, relative to the <body>
   * we need to add the source element's offsetLeft and offsetTop to the returned values.
   */
  const { width, height, ...relativeToElem } = getRenderedBox(canvas);
  const bbox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const left = relativeToElem.left + canvas.offsetLeft;
  const top  = relativeToElem.top  + canvas.offsetTop;

  const witness = document.querySelector(".witness");
  witness.style.setProperty("left",   `${left}px`);
  witness.style.setProperty("top",    `${top}px`);
  witness.style.setProperty("width",  `${width}px`);
  witness.style.setProperty("height", `${height}px`);
};
const observer = new ResizeObserver(([entry]) => {
  updateWitness();
});
observer.observe(canvas);

// To update our test settings
document.getElementById("object_fit_select").onchange = (evt) => {
  canvas.style.setProperty("--object-fit", evt.target.value);
  updateWitness();
};
document.getElementById("object_position_x").oninput = (evt) => {
  canvas.style.setProperty("--object-position-x", evt.target.value);
  updateWitness();
};
document.getElementById("object_position_y").oninput = (evt) => {
  canvas.style.setProperty("--object-position-y", evt.target.value);
  updateWitness();
};
document.getElementById("canvas_width").oninput = (evt) => {
  canvas.width = evt.target.value;
  init();
  updateWitness();
};
document.getElementById("canvas_height").oninput = (evt) => {
  canvas.height = evt.target.value;
  init();
  updateWitness();
};
init();
```

```css
canvas {
  --object-fit: contain;
  --object-position-x: center;
  --object-position-y: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  object-fit: var(--object-fit);
  object-position: var(--object-position-x) var(--object-position-y);
  outline: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
}
.resizable {
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
.witness {
  position: absolute;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="witness"></div>
<label>object-fit: <select id="object_fit_select">
  <option>contain</option>
  <option>cover</option>
  <option>fill</option>
  <option>none</option>
  <option>scale-down</option>
  </select></label><br>
<label>x-position: <input id="object_position_x" value="center"></label><br>
<label>y-position: <input id="object_position_y" value="center"></label><br>
<label>canvas width: <input id="canvas_width" value="600"></label><br>
<label>canvas height: <input id="canvas_height" value="150"></label><br>

<div class="resizable">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="150"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here is with a `<video>` element:

```js
// Some helpers
/**
 * Returns the intrinsic* width & height of most media sources in the Web API
 * (at least the closest we can get to it)
 */
function getResourceDimensions(source) {
  if (source.videoWidth) {
    return { width: source.videoWidth, height: source.videoHeight };
  }
  if (source.naturalWidth) {
    return { width: source.naturalWidth, height: source.naturalHeight };
  }
  if (source.width) {
    return { width: source.width, height: source.height };
  }
  return null;
}
function isRelative(length) {
  return length?.match?.(/%$/);
}
/**
 * Parses the component values of "object-position"
 * Returns the position in px
 */
function parsePositionAsPx(str, bboxSize, objectSize) {
  const num = parseFloat(str);
  if (isRelative(str)) {
    const ratio = num / 100;
    return (bboxSize * ratio) - (objectSize * ratio);
  }
  return num;
}
function parseObjectPosition(position, bbox, object) {
  const [left, top] = position.split(" ");
  return {
    left: parsePositionAsPx(left, bbox.width, object.width),
    top:  parsePositionAsPx(top, bbox.height, object.height)
   };
}

/**
 * Returns the BBox of the rendered object content 
 * relative to the element's box.
 */
function getRenderedBox(elem) {
  let { objectFit, objectPosition } = getComputedStyle(elem);
  const bbox   = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  const object = getResourceDimensions(elem);
  
  if (objectFit === "scale-down") {
    objectFit = (bbox.width < object.width || bbox.height < object.height)
      ? "contain" : "none";
  }
  if (objectFit === "none") {
    const { left, top } = parseObjectPosition(objectPosition, bbox, object);
    return { left, top, ...object }
  }
  if (objectFit === "contain") {
    const objectRatio = object.height / object.width;
    const bboxRatio   = bbox.height / bbox.width;
    const width  = bboxRatio > objectRatio ? bbox.width : bbox.height / objectRatio;
    const height = bboxRatio > objectRatio ? bbox.width * objectRatio : bbox.height;
    const {left, top} = parseObjectPosition(objectPosition, bbox, {width, height});
    return { left, top, width, height };
  }
  if (objectFit === "fill") {
    // Relative positioning is discarded with `object-fit: fill`,
    // so we need to check here if it's relative or not
    const [posLeft, posTop] = objectPosition.split(" ");
    const {left, top} = parseObjectPosition(objectPosition, bbox, object);
    return {
      left: isRelative(posLeft) ? 0 : left,
      top: isRelative(posTop) ? 0 : top,
      width: bbox.width,
      height: bbox.height,
    };
  }
  if (objectFit === "cover") {
    const minRatio = Math.min(bbox.width / object.width, bbox.height / object.height);
    let width  = object.width  * minRatio;
    let height = object.height * minRatio;
    let outRatio  = 1;
    if (width < bbox.width) {
      outRatio = bbox.width / width;
    }
    if (Math.abs(outRatio - 1) < 1e-14 && height < bbox.height) {
      outRatio = bbox.height / height;
    }
    width  *= outRatio;
    height *= outRatio;
    
    const { left, top } = parseObjectPosition(objectPosition, bbox, {width, height});
    return { left, top, width, height };
  }
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Usage example - Move a box around the rendered area
const video = document.querySelector("video");

function updateWitness() {
  /**
   * `getRenderedBox()` returns the position relative to the source element's box
   * Since our witness element is absolutely positionned, relative to the <body>
   * we need to add the source element's offsetLeft and offsetTop to the returned values.
   */
  const { width, height, ...relativeToElem } = getRenderedBox(video);
  const bbox = video.getBoundingClientRect();
  const left = relativeToElem.left + video.offsetLeft;
  const top  = relativeToElem.top  + video.offsetTop;

  const witness = document.querySelector(".witness");
  witness.style.setProperty("left",   `${left}px`);
  witness.style.setProperty("top",    `${top}px`);
  witness.style.setProperty("width",  `${width}px`);
  witness.style.setProperty("height", `${height}px`);
};
const observer = new ResizeObserver(([entry]) => {
  updateWitness();
});
video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => observer.observe(video), { once: true });

// To update our test settings
document.getElementById("object_fit_select").onchange = (evt) => {
  video.style.setProperty("--object-fit", evt.target.value);
  updateWitness();
};
document.getElementById("object_position_x").oninput = (evt) => {
  video.style.setProperty("--object-position-x", evt.target.value);
  updateWitness();
};
document.getElementById("object_position_y").oninput = (evt) => {
  video.style.setProperty("--object-position-y", evt.target.value);
  updateWitness();
};
```

```css
video {
  --object-fit: contain;
  --object-position-x: center;
  --object-position-y: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  object-fit: var(--object-fit);
  object-position: var(--object-position-x) var(--object-position-y);
  outline: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
}
.resizable {
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
.witness {
  position: absolute;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="witness"></div>
<label>object-fit: <select id="object_fit_select">
  <option>contain</option>
  <option>cover</option>
  <option>fill</option>
  <option>none</option>
  <option>scale-down</option>
  </select></label><br>
<label>x-position: <input id="object_position_x" value="center"></label><br>
<label>y-position: <input id="object_position_y" value="center"></label><br>

<div class="resizable">
  <video
    muted autoplay controls loop
    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Fine-tuned-Bee-Flower-Coevolutionary-State-Hidden-within-Multiple-Pollination-Interactions-srep03988-s6.ogv"
    ></video>
</div>
```